# Can't find adb, but I've really looked hard

Tags: android, adb

I know this question has been asked many times - I've read them all and followed most of the suggestions.

I have a new computer, windows 10, so a clean install of AS 3.5.3 . All fine, except trying to get adb to work. I get 'Unable to locate ADB' when after finding no devices I try to restart ADB.

There's also a series of error messages in the event log:

18:16   Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

18:16   Unable to open connection to: localhost/127.0.0.1:5037, due to: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

18:16   Connection attempts: 1

18:16   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

18:16   * daemon started successfully

adb.exe is visible in the right place in platform-tools. But I've tried deleting and reinstalling platform-tools. Reinstalling AS, and not using old setup configurations. I've run AS as an administrator, checked file properties in platform-tools, rebooted the computer, I don't have antivirus except windows defender, and I've run that over the platform-tools folder and it didn't object to that... so I've run out of ideas! The setup looks just the same as in my old computer, and everything works on my old computer (but slowly!).

Any other suggestions? Are those error messages significant.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I should have said I was trying to connect adb using wifi. I installed and android wifi adb plugin (File, Settings, Plugins) and now it's working.

I have 2 other machines with AS on them, and adb over wifi works fine and I never had to do this before.

Edit: I have been asked not to use this post as an answer. It's true, my experience doesn't offer a useful solution to anyone (can't be sure that installing the adb plugin actually helped) but adb is working now, so I don't need anyone bothering themselves trying to figure out a problem that no longer exists. In that sense, it's an answer.

Comment: Edit you question please instead of creating an answer.